# tmp table not growing when running ALTER to add new column

Tags: mysql, alter, percona, datadirectory

I have about a 25 GB table that I have to add a column to.

I run a script and when I execute it, I can see the temp table in the data directory but it stays stuck at about 480K. I can see in processlist that the ALTER is running and there are no issues.

If I kill the script after a long period of activity, then in processlist the query remains in "killed" state and the tmp file will start growing until the query is LITERALLY killed (ie., goes from "killed" state in processlist to disappearing off of the processlist altogether).

When I run the following (before killing the query):

```
select * from global_temporary_tables\G
```

it doesn't show any rows being added either.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what your "ps" output report may show has nothing to do with anything.  Don't rely upon what "ps" says: it includes stale data.

If the process has been killed (SIGKILL, not SIGTERM), I guarantee you it is no longer delivering any output to anywhere.  If it's been SIGTERMed, it depends what signal handlers you've attached.  I'm going to hazard a wild guess that you haven't registered any signal handlers.

Most production DBMS set up storage in chunks.  X amount of space is obtained, which may contain "slack" room that enables rows and/or columns to be added (I do NOT say that the two mechanisms are identical).  Just because something didn't grow in a manner that you could perceive doesn't mean that the changes weren't made.  Why not check out the data dictionary, interrogating the current structure of the table.

Did you COMMIT your changes?  In some DBMS, DDL operations are regarded as committable/rollbackable (yecch) events.